# Empty first line in razor mvc 4 rc

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I've migrated from mvc 3 to mvc 4 and encountered with the following problem.

```
@using InvoiceDocflow.Controllers
@{
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
}
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dc>
    @foreach (var dcLink in (IEnumerable<DcLink>)ViewData["SupportedDcs"])
    {
        <link rel="@dcLink.RelUri.ToString()" href="@dcLink.DcUri.ToString()" />
    }
</dc>
```

This is my view. My layout is just one line

```
@RenderBody()
```

So in mvc 3 `<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` appeared in the first line, but now, its appears on the second line, leaving th first line empty.

[image]

Can I make it render on the first line as it was in mvc 3?

By the way.

```
@using InvoiceDocflow.Controllers
@{
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
}<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

This would work, but this is not what I whant to do at all.

Comment: I don't see anything bsd in the Mvc4 behaviour: it copy in the page all cariage returns that are out of a code block, so if you don't want the carriage return you have to put <?xml.....on the same line. What is wrong with this?

Comment: I don't need code block to implicitly influence on output. It's just wrong. It was ok in MVC 3.

Comment: The point is that the carriage return is out of the code block so it is reported in the outpunt. While Vb is line oriented C# is not. It is evident tham Mvc 4 take a different definition of code block than Mvc3..but I dont think one can say that the Mvc 4 definition "is wrong" ...just different.

Comment: Why don't you use a custom action result to generate your XML? Creating XML manually as you do inside a view instead of using an XML parser is very dangerous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Temporary fix? ActionFilter and strip out the empty first line? Clearly you could also do other minification on the response if suitable.

```
public class TranslationFilter : MemoryStream
{
    private Stream filter = null;

    public TranslationFilter(HttpResponseBase httpResponseBase)
    {
        filter = httpResponseBase.Filter;
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        var response = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

        // remove all newlines
        response = response.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");

        /* remove just first empty line
          if (response.Substring(0, 2) == "\r\n")
        {
            response = response.Substring(2, response.Length - 2);
        } */

        filter.Write(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response), offset, UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(response));
    }
}

public class ResponseFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public ResponseFilter()
    {
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Filter = new TranslationFilter(filterContext.HttpContext.Response);
    }
}
```

And add it onto the Controller method?

```
[ResponseFilter]
public ActionResult Index()
{
return View();
}
```

Comment: This is not the full solution. New lines appear on every @{} block (not only first one), so I'd prefere the solution wich will handle that. But, I'll accept your question, if there will be no alternative.

Comment: Adjusted to remove all new lines, but obviously this may not be what you want - makes it harder to read html source in browser. Glad I have been of assistance though.

Comment: It's not about deleting all new lines. It's about deleting lines coused by @{} blocks.

Comment: I believe the bug is somewhere in [WhitespaceRewriter.cs](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Razor/Parser/WhitespaceRewriter.cs) or [RazorParser.cs](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Razor/Parser/RazorParser.cs). Can anyone send the pull request with the correction?

Answer (score 7):

I ran into a similar problem with blank lines at the top of the page when trying to return a cache manifest file. Solution, Add a Response.Write("..."), this will be at the first line of the page.

```
 @{
     Layout = null;
     Response.Write("CACHE MANIFEST");

} .......
```

Comment: This underappreciated answer worked for me.  XML files must have the doctype on the first line without any leading white space.  The @{ } section  gets executed before anything else on the page.  So the Response.Write() will also get executed before Razor adds the leading extraneous white space ahead of the page content. Moving the doctype to the top of the view, as suggested in some other answers, did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question but I found it when I was searching for a solution to this problem.
Since no one has an easy solution, here is mine:

I was able to fix this by using a partial view instead of a normal view.
I believe the problem comes down to the layout, even if you set it to null it still seems to add a blank first line. The @{} ads a blank line also, so you must move it to the bottom of your view.

So just add a partial view and have your controller return the partial view as such:

```
public ActionResult GenerateXML()
{
    return PartialView("_XML");
}
```

Then in your partial view you will need to set it up like this (with your @{} at the bottom):

```
@model string
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response>
    <message>@Model</message>
</response>
@{ Response.ContentType = "text/xml";}
```

This will result in an HTML source of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response>
    <message>Response Message</message>
</response>
```

I hope this helps others who run into this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I know you suggested just moving the tag to the end of the `@{}` but why not place it before that. Moreover, is this blank space causing an error or an issue? You can clearly see that it is because of whitespace created by your code and not from mvc or razor.

Perhaps something like this:

```
@using InvoiceDocflow.Controllers
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
@{
 Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions above worked for me, so after spending a long time trying to fix it - it should be very easy since it's just an empty line - I wrote a blog post about it.

http://devstuffs.wordpress.com/2014/02/07/first-line-empty-in-razor/

Comment: "Solution 2" worked great (I'm generating a cache manifest file). Thanks for sharing!

Comment: The suggestion by evanswd in the comment worked fine for me and was really easy!

Comment: Please either inline summary of the solution in answer or convert this link to comment.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the similar problem this way:

**_ViewStart.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    Response.Write("<!DOCTYPE html>");
}
```

**Another .cshtml**

```
@model ViewModel<EshopWebsiteOrder>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Finally, it makes sense define common DOCTYPE on one place.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple fix without the ResponseFilter. Simply put the @using at the bottom of the cshtml file:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dc>
    @foreach (var dcLink in (IEnumerable<DcLink>)ViewData["SupportedDcs"])
    {
        <link rel="@dcLink.RelUri.ToString()" href="@dcLink.DcUri.ToString()" />
    }
</dc>
@using InvoiceDocflow.Controllers
@{
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you move:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

into the top of a Layout template then have your xml page inherit that and output your xml data it should work.